# How to configure springfox to unwrap reactive types such as Mono and Flux without having to explicitly specify response type in @ApiResponse

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, spring-webflux, swagger-ui, springfox

I'm using springfox 3.0.0 for reactive support, and am using `@EnableSwagger2WebFlux` on my swagger config.

My swagger config is as follows:

```
@Bean
public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .apiInfo(apiInfo())
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage(basePackage))
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build()
            .securityContexts(Lists.newArrayList(securityContext()))
            .securitySchemes(Lists.newArrayList(apiKey()))
            .globalOperationParameters(operationParameters());
}
```

I have a simple controller, as shown below:

```
  @CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*", maxAge = 3600)
  @RestController
  @RequestMapping("/")
  public class ApiController {

    @ApiOperation(value = "get all partners", authorizations = {@Authorization(value = "Bearer")})
    @RequestMapping(value = "/partner",
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE}
    )
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Request succeeded")
    })
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<Flux<PartnerDTO>>> getAllPartners(
            @ApiIgnore ServerHttpRequest httpRequest
    ) {
        return ...
    }
```

When springfox generates the documentation, it has the following type:
[image]

And this type is useless in my API operation:
[image]

I know I can fix this by specifying the response type in @ApiOperation, but I'm trying to avoid that, e.g.

```
@ApiOperation(value = "get all partners", authorizations = {@Authorization(value = "Bearer")})
@RequestMapping(value = "/partner",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE}
)
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Request succeeded", response = PartnerDTO.class)
})
public Mono<ResponseEntity<Flux<PartnerDTO>>> getAllPartners(
        @ApiIgnore ServerHttpRequest httpRequest
) {
```

I don't like this approach as it's a manual process and and thus prone to errors.
I'd like some automatic way to do the following conversion:

```
Flux<T> -> T[] (since flux emits 0...N elements)
Mono<T> -> T
ResponseEntity<T> -> T
```

And of course it would have to be recursive (e.g. `Mono<ResponseEntity<Flux<T>>> -> T`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I went through the code of springfox trying to find some entry point for custom type resolving, and luckily it has a `HandlerMethodResolver` which can be injected externally.

I added a custom implementation of this resolver in my swagger config class:

```
@Bean
@Primary
public HandlerMethodResolver fluxMethodResolver(TypeResolver resolver) {
    return new HandlerMethodResolver(resolver) {
        @Override
        public ResolvedType methodReturnType(HandlerMethod handlerMethod) {
            var retType = super.methodReturnType(handlerMethod);

            // we unwrap Mono, Flux, and as a bonus - ResponseEntity
            while (
                    retType.getErasedType() == Mono.class
                    || retType.getErasedType() == Flux.class
                    || retType.getErasedType() == ResponseEntity.class
            ) {
                if ( retType.getErasedType() == Flux.class ) {
                    // treat it as an array
                    var type = retType.getTypeBindings().getBoundType(0);
                    retType = new ResolvedArrayType(type.getErasedType(), type.getTypeBindings(), type);
                } else {
                    retType = retType.getTypeBindings().getBoundType(0);
                }
            }

            return retType;
        }
    };
}
```

Which does exactly what I need.

[image]

It automatically converts `Mono<ResponseEntity<Flux<PartnerDTO>>>` to `PartnerDTO[]`, and `Mono<ResponseEntity<Mono<PartnerDTO>>>` to `PartnerDTO`.

**EDIT:**: I changed this implementation to convert Flux to T[], as it should have been from the start.

Comment: Works great thanks. Yet i had to add this the docket configuration ,genericModelSubstitutes(Mono.class, Flux.class, Publisher.class) To be able correct show correctly the parameters

Comment: It's too much work. Use `springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui` instead of `springfox` and you will have the functionality out-of-the-box. See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/69298342/2886891

Answer (score 2):

You can also follow Sprinfox example:

- declare a [RecursiveAlternateTypeRule.java](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/blob/master/springfox-petstore-webflux/src/main/java/springfox/documentation/schema/RecursiveAlternateTypeRule.java)
- add it as **alternateTypeRules** in your [Swagger Configuration](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/blob/master/springfox-petstore-webflux/src/main/java/springfox/petstore/webflux/PetStoreConfiguration.java)

  ```
  @Configuration
  @EnableSwagger2WebFlux
  public abstract class AbstractSwaggerConfiguration {

  @Autowired
  private TypeResolver resolver;

  @Bean
  public Docket api() {
      return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2) //
          .select().apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any()).paths(PathSelectors.any()) //
          .build()
          .alternateTypeRules(new RecursiveAlternateTypeRule(resolver,
              Arrays.asList(AlternateTypeRules.newRule(resolver.resolve(Mono.class, WildcardType.class), resolver.resolve(WildcardType.class)),
                  AlternateTypeRules.newRule(resolver.resolve(ResponseEntity.class, WildcardType.class), resolver.resolve(WildcardType.class)))))
          .alternateTypeRules(
              new RecursiveAlternateTypeRule(resolver, Arrays.asList(AlternateTypeRules.newRule(resolver.resolve(Flux.class, WildcardType.class), resolver.resolve(List.class, WildcardType.class)),
                  AlternateTypeRules.newRule(resolver.resolve(ResponseEntity.class, WildcardType.class), resolver.resolve(WildcardType.class)))));
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

`Springfox`, as it seems, [missed the boat](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58953513/2886891). Use `springdoc-openapi` instead. We have had also other issues with `springfox`, not only the missing `webflux` support, and we happily switched to `springdoc-openapi`

For webflux applications, all you need is to [add dependency](https://springdoc.org/#spring-webflux-support) `springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui`:

```xml
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
      <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.9</version>
</dependency>
```

No additional configuration is needed, and the `Mono` and `Flux` will be unwrapped out-of-the-box.

There is also a [manual](https://springdoc.org/migrating-from-springfox.html) how to migrate from `springfox` to `springdoc-openapi`.

If you need to programmatically customize the configuration, you define an [`OpenAPI`](https://javadoc.io/doc/io.swagger.core.v3/swagger-models/latest/io/swagger/v3/oas/models/OpenAPI.html) bean like this:

```java
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.OpenAPI;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.info.Info;

@Configuration
public class OpenApi30Config {
    @Bean
    public OpenAPI openApi() {
        return new OpenAPI()
           .info(new Info().title("My Application")
                .description("This is my application")
                .version("1.0")
            )
            // and lot of other configuration possible here
            ;
    }
}
```